# Why Application Launcher text is smudged in Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: kubuntu

I had faced this problem in other distros with KDE Plasma I used before.

Note that text typed in the Search box appears correctly.

I guess maybe this is because of graphical or font issue instead a bug.

[image]

```
System:    Host: swapnil-desktop Kernel: 4.15.0-45-generic i686 bits: 32 gcc: 7.3.0 Console: tty 1
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: Intel model: DG41RQ v: AAE54511-203 serial: <filter>
           BIOS: Intel v: RQG4110H.86A.0009.2009.0108.1005 date: 01/08/2009
CPU:       Dual core Pentium E5300 (-MCP-) arch: Penryn rev.10 cache: 2048 KB
           flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10400
           clock speeds: max: 2600 MHz 1: 1200 MHz 2: 1200 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GF119 [GeForce GT 610] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1360x768@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.107 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 NVIDIA GF119 HDMI Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-45-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1504.3GB (1.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST3500413AS size: 500.1GB temp: 32C
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: ST1000DM003 size: 1000.2GB temp: 32C
           ID-3: USB /dev/sdc model: Storage_Media size: 4.0GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 98G used: 15G (16%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 4.01GB used: 0.10GB (3%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdc1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:40C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 158 Uptime: 9 min Memory: 1457.8/2008.1MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191) inxi: 2.3.56
```

[image]

Comment: @DKBose Thanks typed text don't smudge. I've posted information.

Comment: Please see https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/75115-Semi-scrambled-text-in-Launcher-GUI?p=425459#post425459. There are suggestions related to your graphics card and the resolution of "1360x768" which is unusual. "1366x768" is normal. If you can't access the link, let me know.